# Can't load any packages in R

Tags: r

I can't load any packages in R. Every time I try to load a package, it reports

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in 
loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required.
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the package from within RStudio by running on the console pane

```
install.packages('rlang')
```

If this fails due to a locked directory, exit RStudio, open a Terminal window and run

```
R -q -e "install.packages('rlang')"
```

Restart RStudio and check the package version with

```
packageVersion('rlang')
```

Comment: When I tried ```install.packages("rlang")```, it reports ```trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/rlang_1.0.4.zip' ```, which is still the old version. How can I get the latest version of ```rlang```? Thanks.

Comment: Version 1.0.4 is the current version. https://rlang.r-lib.org/

Comment: @GuofengWu The error message you're getting says `but >= 1.0.1 is required` so version 1.0.4 solves it.

Comment: Thanks. But this time, the error message became: ```namespace ‘pillar’ 1.6.4 is already loaded, but >= 1.7.0 is required```. What should I do now? Thank you very much!

Comment: Reinstall the package, `install.packages('pillar')`. Follow the steps in my answer.